# 404 not working, going to homepage; how to fix?

Tags: themes, 404-error, mod-rewrite

Whenever I call a non-existent page, say http://www.example.com/foobar/, it should invoke the `404.php` theme template file.

In my case, however, the site redirects to the homepage, `/`

I'm not sure what I did in the past to enable this.

How can I ensure that 404.php takes precedence when a file is non-existent?

FYI:

My .htaccess file is below...

I'm not sure where the first two `IfModule`s came from. I recently tried and disabled caching plugins. I have gone to the Permalinks settings and re-saved.

I am running Multisite. The site is the primary site in question. And I may need to retain the ability to power multiple sites off it.

Removing...

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

... doesn't work.

Removing the entire portion after `# BEGIN WordPress` results in a server-level 404: "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp\-content/+debug\.log$
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <Files "debug.log">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    </Files>
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Modified for Multisite https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-to-create-a-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel
# Previous here:
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.php [L]



# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 1000
   php_value max_input_time 1000
   php_value max_input_vars 8000
   php_value memory_limit 1024M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was the multi-site config attribute `NOBLOGREDIRECT`

This had been set in wp-config.php...

```
// Redirect non-existent Multisite subdomain calls to www primary site
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.example.com' );
```

This prevents a valid 404 appearing since it is always interpreted as a bad call to a subdomain.

There are two solutions:

1. Comment it out
2. As stated by [@brij's post](https://techbrij.com/wordpress-404-redirect-homepage-fix) (discovered through Google), override it:

> In wp-config.php, NOBLOGREDIRECT is defined so that when someone
>   enters a subdomain that does not exist on your site to redirect to
>   whatever url you wish it to. But the bad thing is when someone tries
>   to access the page of domain that doesn’t exist, it redirects to
>   NOBLOGREDIRECT defined location instead of throwing 404. To fix it,
>   add following PHP code in functions.php or any related file
>
> `<?php remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_redirect_404' ); ?>`